# C# constructor overloading invalid arguments

Tags: c#

Trying to execute the code below prevents me from moving forward.
In my "Theline" class I have a constructor that accepts two arguments (int) but the error message I get says "Cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.Point' to 'int'" What am I missing?

```
public static void Main()
     {
     Point a0 = new Point(0, 0);
     Point a1 = new Point(-1, -1);
     Theline line = new Theline(a0, a1);
     }
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that there is no way to convert from a Point to an int. Why do you think this is legal code? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You should change your `TheLine` class constructor to accept `Point`s because to define the line you need two points.

Comment: in 2d scene point have two `int`s (x and y). if you want to create line from two points you have to pass in `Theline` two points. and there are some drawing algorithms such as Bresenham's Line Algorithm you can search for that in google.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Theline` connstuctor accepts `int` and you send it a `Point` object...

Simply change it to

```
Theline line = new Theline(a0.X, a1.Y);
```

You can either change the `Theline` constructor parameters to  type of `Point`.

Or anything else you need..

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, what Slashy says.

Or since you want a line to be created, make your TheLine constructor accept 2 points instead of ints.

Comment: How do I do that exactly?
public TheLine(int a0.X, a0.Y, a1.X, a1.Y)?

Comment: It depends on your implementation of the Theline class, can you show me the code?
Your suggested answer would work if you change your constructor so it accepts 4 ints. But letting it accept 2 Points seems more logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to use the Point, then I guess you could try:

```
public Theline(Point pointA, Point pointB) : this (pointA.X, pointB.Y)
{
}
```